# Idiomatic Rust: should string tokenization be a function, a special trait or a TryFrom trait?

Tags: string, rust, error-handling, tokenize

I split a line of text on whitespace and want to convert all snippets that are of the form similar `ALA`, `LEU`, `VAL` and such into a `Token` type. The matching is simple, but i'm new to rust and am not sure how to reason about implementing the conversion itself.

I implemented it as a `TryFrom` trait for a `String`(see below) because for most string-snippets in the initial text the conversion will fail so i thought it's a good way to just have a filtering mechanism. Should i be rather using a standalone function? How would i implement this for a `&str` eventually(i failed this time because of borrowing rules)?

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum AminoAcid {
    VAL,    GLN,    ARG,    LEU,
    THR,    TYR,    SER,    PRO,
    CYS,    GLY,    ALA,    MET,
}
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Coordinate {
    x: f32,    y: f32,    z: f32,
}
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Token {
    Coordinate(Coordinate),
    AminoAcid(AminoAcid),
}

fn match_string(tgt: &str) -> Option<Token> {
    match tgt {
        "VAL" => Some(AminoAcid::VAL.into()),
        ..., // etc.
        "ALA" => Some(AminoAcid::ALA.into()),
        "MET" => Some(AminoAcid::MET.into()),
        _ => None,
    }


impl TryFrom<String> for Token {
    type Error = ();
    fn try_from(value: String) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        let x = match match_string(&value) {
            Some(uu) => Ok(uu),
            None => Err(()),
        };
        x
    }
}

fn process_line(line: &str) -> Vec<Token> {
    let tokens = line.split_whitespace().collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    let mut results: Vec<Token> = vec![];
    for template_string in tokens {
        match template_string.to_string().try_into() {
            Ok(token) => {
                println!("Parsed to Token : {:?}", token);
                results.push(token)
            }
            _ => continue,
        };
    }
    return results;
}
```

I'm mostly, again, interested in the trade-offs that an experienced Rust user would think. Thank you.

Comment: This question is mainly opinion-based; there are almost no differences. For the record, [rustc uses a custom function](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/77497c74f9268ccf91d7b4c17f23bf07117d7433/compiler/rustc_lexer/src/lib.rs#L301), and that what I would do too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways to accomplish this, but it would be a disservice to not suggest [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) as an idiomatic way to parse values from strings:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum AminoAcid {
    VAL,    GLN,    ARG,    LEU,
    THR,    TYR,    SER,    PRO,
    CYS,    GLY,    ALA,    MET,
}

struct AminoAcidParseError;

impl FromStr for AminoAcid {
    type Err = AminoAcidParseError;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<AminoAcid, AminoAcidParseError> {
        match s {
            "VAL" => Ok(AminoAcid::VAL),
            // ... others
            "ALA" => Ok(AminoAcid::ALA),
            "MET" => Ok(AminoAcid::MET),
            _ => Err(AminoAcidParseError),
        }
    }
}

fn process_line(line: &str) {
    for s in line.split_whitespace() {
        match s.parse::<AminoAcid>() {
            Ok(a) => println!("Parsed to AminoAcid : {:?}", a),
            Err(_) => {},
        }
    }
}
```

See a full example on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=19c1f3b8f02a2c1ba8b6234457dc2ae2).

Implementing this trait allows you to call [`.parse()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) on any `str` to fallibly get the value. I've only covered it for your `AminoAcid` type, but you can see how to do it for `Token` and beyond.